# how to convert pcm raw data to mp3 without using any library in android

Tags: android

First of all I must tell you that I am new in android. I want to combine multiple  .pcm (audio file) files and after that convert this file into .mp3 file. It is easy to combine them . But my problem is i can't convert this file into .mp3.I heard about LAMEOnJ but i want to convert it without using any library.Is there any other way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to do this without a library?

Comment: If i convert the file without using library then why i use this? That's why i want to know is there any other way?

Comment: of course you can implement a mp3 encoder, what is the problem?

Comment: Problem is ,i don't understand how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can always do this by hand, **if** you're capable of it.

Transform from the [PCM-Specs](http://www.topherlee.com/software/pcm-tut-wavformat.html) to the [MP3-Specs](http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/MP3Format.html)

But this is not an easy task at all. Maybe look through the Android docs which formats are supported natively, and what formats can be output without a 3rd party library.